# Find words and create new value in different column pandas dataframe with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

suppose I have a dataframe which contains:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'Alice', 'Peter', 'Sue'],
                   'Job': ['Dentist', 'Blogger', 'Cook', 'Cook'], 
                  'Sector': ['Health', 'Entertainment', '', '']})
```

and I want to find all 'cooks', whether in capital letters or not and assign them to the column 'Sector' with a value called 'gastronomy', how do I do that? And without overwriting the other entries in the column 'Sector'? Thanks!

Comment: `df['Sector']= np.where(df.Job.str.lower().eq('cook'), 'gastronomy', df.Sector)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach:

```
df.loc[df.Job.str.lower().eq('cook'), 'Sector'] = 'gastronomy'
```

---

```
print(df)

    Name      Job         Sector
0   John  Dentist         Health
1  Alice  Blogger  Entertainment
2  Peter     Cook     gastronomy
3    Sue     Cook     gastronomy
```

Comment: or `df.Job.str.casefold().eq('cook')` using casefold :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) with `regex` and a regex flag for not case sensitive (`?i`):

```
df.loc[df['Job'].str.match('(?i)cook'), 'Sector'] = 'gastronomy'
```

**Output**

```
    Name      Job         Sector
0  John   Dentist  Health       
1  Alice  Blogger  Entertainment
2  Peter  Cook     gastronomy   
3  Sue    Cook     gastronomy
```